# Hibernate XML mapping - create new field after another AND add it into a multi-column constraint

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, mapping, key

I have a problem with hibernate xml mapping. I want to add a new field "newField" in an already existing db schema.

I want to insert this field after another (size in the example), AND be part of a multi-column unique key constraint.

The xml mapping is the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false" default-cascade="all" package="xxx">
<class name="A" table="As" discriminator-value="a">
    <id name="dbId" column="db_id" type="long">
        <generator class="IdentityGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="tag" type="string"/>        
    <property name="created" type="timestamp" insert="false" update="false" generated="insert"/>

    <properties name="key" unique="true">            
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true"/>            
        <property name="version" column="version" length="80" type="string"/>
    </properties>

<property name="size" column="size" type="long"/>
<property name="newField" column="new_field" type="long"/>

</class>
```

If I add the property of my new field into the multi-column "properties", it will be created two times.

Do you know if hibernate has a way to do this ?

Thanks for your help

Joris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer @Sebri.

I found the solution, I just replaced index by unique-key property

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false" default-cascade="all" package="xxx">
```

```
<id name="dbId" column="db_id" type="long">
    <generator class="IdentityGenerator"/>
</id>
<discriminator column="tag" type="string"/>        
<property name="created" type="timestamp" insert="false" update="false" generated="insert"/>           
<property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true" unique-key="key"/>            
<property name="version" column="version" length="80" type="string" unique-key="key"/>
<property name="size" column="size" type="long"/>
<property name="newField" column="new_field" type="long" unique-key="key"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_nom` ON `As` (`name`,`version`,`new_field`);
```

then

```
<property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true" index="UNIQUE_IDX_KEY"/>            
<property name="version" column="version" length="80" type="string" index="UNIQUE_IDX_KEY"/>


<property name="newField" column="new_field" index="UNIQUE_IDX_KEY" />
```